# Java elasticsearch spring-data set different index field name

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch java-api in combination with spring-data and have a problem with indexing a document. 
I want a different name for an indexed field. That means not the same as in the java code:

Domainobject:

```
@Document(indexName = "testindex", type = "message")
public class MessageObject {

@Id
private String  unid;

@FieldNameInElasticIndex(value = "javaMessage")  // I want anything like that
private String message;

private String secondMessage;

private String thirdMessage;

...

getters & setters

...

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MessageObjectRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MessageObject, Long> {


}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageObjectRepository repository;


    public void addRegistrationObject(MessageObject msg) {

        repository.save(msg);
    }
}
```

So....

is it possible to change the name so the index would look like:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "message",
        "_id": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "unid": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
          "javaMessage": "Hello",  // <--- this is what I want (javaMessage)
          "secondMessage": null,
          "thirdMessage": "Third",
```

instead of

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "message",
        "_id": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "unid": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
          "message": "Hello",  // <--- this is NOT what I want (java name: message)
          "secondMessage": null,
          "thirdMessage": "Third",
```

?

Comment: Have you tried `@JsonProperty("javaMessage")` ?

Comment: It works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is simply to use the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the field and give the name you want to use during the JSON serialization:

```
@JsonProperty("javaMessage")
private String message;
```

Comment: There is not a _single_ mention of `@JsonProperty` in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/ ! How can this be overlooked in the documentation?